# 9 volt battery and a 10 watt IR LED

Tags: led, infrared

I connected a 9V battery to a 10V IR led and the brightness lasts 3 seconds before "dimming" down to a soft glow.

How do I maintain the initial brightness?

Do I plug in a few AA or do I buy a 30 or 50 watt IR led chip?

Comment: You can do Watt U want but if you don't know Ohm's Law for Diode resistance and current and thermal resistance with no thermal heatsink and sensor, it will probably fail.

Answer (score 1):

You don't maintain the brightness at the initial level, not when using a 9V battery.

10W at 10V requires 1A of current.

A 9V battery is designed to deliver maybe 100mA for a few hours. Drawing 1A sucks it dry in just about no time.

You need a power source that can deliver more current for a longer time.

You need a **much** larger battery.

For the 10W IR light, you might use a bunch of D cells.   Six in series to get 9V.  They should provide enough current for a usefully long time - hours rather than seconds.

For the larger lights you mention you'll probably need something larger.  Like, motorcycle or car battery sized.